# How to escape double quotes in a WCAT scenario file?

Tags: wcat

Using WCAT 6.3, I'd like to set an http header exactly like this including the double quotes around the ETag:

```
If-None-Match: "a52391cbf838cd1:0"
```

How do I escape the double quotes in the scenario file? This is the snippet from my scenario file that is not working:

```
request
{
  url = "/css/navigation.css";
  setheader
  {
    name  = "If-None-Match";
    value = ""a52391cbf838cd1:0"";
  }
  statuscode = 304;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCAT is based in C and the scenario file uses some of the C syntax including its escape character. The correct syntax is:

```
  setheader
  {
    name  = "If-None-Match";
    value = "\"a52391cbf838cd1:0\"";
  }
```